# Laptop for programming and light gaming under $500?

Tags: laptop, gaming, development

So. I have yet another question that requires some advice.

I've been tasked by my uncle to find a laptop for my cousin sister's senior college years. She has decided to go into IT Software Engineering. I have also been given a budget to spend around $500.

I have looked at Core i5 and Core i7 Laptops primarily, but either these laptops are too outdated, or just don't meet my minimum requirements model. She will coding in what I assume will be Java, or at the very least Delphi, so the CPU is a game changer here. I have considered Atom, but the specs of the CPU set is putting me off the whole Atom lineup.

I want the laptop to have the following specifications -->

1. Any form of Quad Core CPU clocked at over 2.7GHz. Not too worried about whether the CPU is Intel or AMD. CPU must have integrated graphics
2. Have at least 4GB RAM. Not too worried if it is DDR3 or DDR4.
3. Some form of SSD Storage, preferably paired with an HDD of some kind
4. If possible, which I doubt, some form of dedicated GPU, whether it be AMD or Nvidia. A stretch, but preferred if possible.
5. Can ship internationally

As for the games she wants to play in her downtime, she wants to play games like Minecraft and maybe CS:GO

Thanks for viewing

Comment: Regarding No. 1 you may want to familiarize yourself with the [megahertz myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megahertz_myth). Here [a 2.6 Ghz 4 core processor marginally beats an 8 core clocked at 4.7](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-6700HQ-vs-AMD-FX-9590/m34954vs1812). Regarding No. 2, 4 GB of RAM typically results in page/swap file lag on Windows. Regarding No 5. Do you have a place you specifically want to ship this laptop to? This can have a non-trivial affect on price due to VAT/Import fees.

Comment: Apologies for the extremely late response. The laptop must be able to ship to South Africa. Regarding the Megahertz Myth, that link is a real eye opener, something to keep in mind for future recommendations.

Comment: It's going to be difficult for me to ship to South Africa in general, are you comfortable being more specific with your location? In addition, $500 is an extremely tight budget, particularly if you want to be able to play CS:GO or Mine-craft. $500 may be enough for a U series intel, and 4 GB of ram, but I think a system build like that would be very lag-gy, especially for software engineering, non-academic in particular.